# Connections stuck in CLOSE_WAIT status

Tags: java, linux, https, jboss7.x

I have a Java application running in JBOSS EAP 6.4.5 on Linux.
Over a period of time as multiple users logs in application then it become inaccessible( connection failed error ) with the warning message on.
**JBWEB003008: Maximum number of threads (1024) created for connector with **address *** **and port ***.******

We have noticed is that most of the connections as in CLOSE_WAIT state.
Server restart helps to resolve this issue temporary.
Not sure what's causing this.

Comment: You need to find out why the local application isn't closing the connections.

Comment: @EJP application is not creating and closing connections. Its handled by JBOSS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the maximum number of threads created for a connector in EAP6. For non-native APR connectors, the maximum number of threads which a connector can handle can be defined by adding the attribute max-connections in the  subsytem as:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
   <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" max-connections="2048"/>
    ...
    </subsystem>
```

For APR connectors (native="true"), the max thread pool size is sized through the org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MAX_THREADS system property instead

Comment: I think it would again hit maximum number of threads (2048) after some time.